# Mass downvotes on 4 December

Tags: support, down-votes

On 4 December, there were many downvotes without explanation. The user used the Recently Active feed to select the questions. Old questions that were bumped by the Community bot were downvoted without explanation. A search through the feed shows many examples of single downvotes without any substantiating comment. The following posts contain downvotes I consider dodgy:

1. [Q and A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/30079/175),
2. [Q](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/30066/175),
3. [A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/30081/175),
4. [Q and A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/32576/175),
5. [A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/24992/175) (and probably Q)
6. [A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/27175/175)
7. [Q and A](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/27087/175)
8. etc...

The user was either being very critical, was in a bad mood, or doesn't understand that it is rude to downvote without giving feedback.

Comment: Do you have a proposal as to what to do?

Comment: Could you explain why you think it is rude to downvote without giving feedback?  Is that just your opinion, or is it a site policy (if so a link would be helpful).

Comment: @AdamBailey A single downvote on a post that hasn't received many votes stands out, and it does not give me much feedback as to what was wrong with the post. When a lower-rep user downvotes, a pop-up box is displayed saying, "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." Try it out on a site where you have low rep.